# jquery post request + response in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to make a post request with jquery in Django. Unfortunately I haven't succeeded yet. Indeed : I only see in firebug a post request which status is 200 and I get the following result (too new to post any image):

https://drive.google.com/a/essec.edu/file/d/0B5MagNFQFkbXeVBNV1pfZC1sbk0/view?usp=sharing

Could anyone help me find what I have done wrong?

My code comes from here :
[Need a simple working ajax example for django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814425/need-a-simple-working-ajax-example-for-django-forms) , so I think it should be correct.

FYI, in settings.py I have commented the csrf line to put away that issue for the time beeing :

"    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',"

views.py:

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')


def ajax_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        name = request.POST['name']
        city = request.POST['city']
        message = name + ' lives in ' + city

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message})) 

    return render(request, 'ajax.html')
```

index.html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<form id="my_form" action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#my_form").submit(function(){
    $.post("",
    {name:"Donald Duck",
     city:"Duckburg",
     },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
        console.log("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
        alert("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^ajax/$', views.ajax_test, name="ajax"),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would bet for your form action. Try setting it to the URL of your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has no "action" defined

```
$.post("",
```

This must have the url defined. Change it to

```
$.post("/ajax/",
```

Also when you implement it properly, don't get rid of the csrf token. You can simply pass the serialized form data (which will include the csrf token).